# Is there an option of GWT CssResource source inheritance?

Tags: java, css, gwt, gxt

Here is my question: for example I have 2 java-classes with appearances for diffrenet components. But they use same basic CSS-files for CssResource style interfaces. Here how this looks:

```
public class FirstAppearance {

    public interface FirstResources extends ClientBundle {
        @Source({"Basic.css", "AnotherBasic.css", "First.css"})
        FirstStyle style();    
    }

    public interface FirstStyle extends CssResource {
    ...
    }
```

And then

```
    public class SecondAppearance {
```

```
    public interface SecondResources extends ClientBundle {
        @Source({"Basic.css", "AnotherBasic.css", "Second.css"})
        SecondStyle style();    
    }

    public interface SecondStyle extends CssResource {
    ...
    }
```

Is there any way to get rid of everytime-definition of **"Basic.css", "AnotherBasic.css"**   in `@Source` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Appearance Pattern](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CellBackedWIdgets) or when you use UIBinder then you could use

```
<Ui:style>
```

Comment: Em...It's not the same what I want, there is no option to add Cutom.css to Deafault.